# return the name of a file using a batch script

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I am trying to write a script that will search a given directory, find files ending in a .ready_go extension, rar them (saving the rar as the file name.rar) and then move onto the next file with the same extensions and do the same.

I am not having luck assigning a variable "filename" to the name of the file found in the loop.  this variable will be used to name the rar archive

so far this is what i have:

```
set dSource=C:\users\admin\desktop\one
set dTarget=\\filesrv1\archives
set fType=*.ready_go

for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /a-d /b /s "%dSource%\%fType%"') do (

    set filename=%%f
    echo %filename%
    echo %dsource%
    pause
)
```

its echo'ing the dsources variable fine, but will not echo the filename variable.

I also tried just "echo %%f" which also did not work.

some help would be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use delayedexpansion since you are setting the varable inside the loop.

try this:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set dSource=C:\users\admin\desktop\one
set dTarget=\\filesrv1\archives
set fType=*.ready_go

for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /a-d /b /s "%dSource%\%fType%"') do (

        set filename=%%f
        echo !filename!
        echo %dsource%
        pause
)
```